# React Native How do I show a marker I get from the server

Tags: react-native

I need to take pointer positions from the server during the map position change and reflect these new pointer positions on the map. how to show this dynamically

App.js

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            markers: [{
                coordinates: {
                    lat:37.189938,
                    lng: 33.217167
                },
                altitude: 0,
                speed: 0,
                course: 0,
            },]
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MapView>

                    {this.state.markers.map((marker, index) =>
                        ( <MapView.Marker
                            key={index}
                            image={require('./assets/arrow.png')}
                            coordinate={marker.coordinates}
                            style={{
                                transform: [
                                    {
                                        rotate: course + 'deg',
                                    },

                                ],
                            }}
                            />
                            ))}
                </MapView>
```

here I am splitting the data from the server

```
    updateMap(message) {
    var [lat, lng, altitude, speed, course] = message.toString().split(',');
    this.setState({
        lat: parseFloat(lat),
        lng: parseFloat(lng),
        altitude,
        speed,
        course,
    });
}
```

Comment: Well whenever you call `updateMap` with different state values your component should re-render. Where are you calling it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not updating your marker value when you getting data from server. Since you are only taking coordinates then its necessary to update coordinates state always. 
Rather than taking `coordinate={marker.coordinates}`, 
take
`coordinate={this.state.coordinates}` in your render marker code.

Initialize your coordinates in the state as empty variables, just like below

```
 this.state = {
     coordinates: {
         lat:0,
         lng:0
    },
 }
```

And update your state of coordinates when your are getting data from server.

```
updateMap(message) {
    var [lat, lng, altitude, speed, course] = message.toString().split(',');
    let tempCoordinates = {
        lat: parseFloat(lat),
        lng: parseFloat(lng),
    } 
    this.setState({
        coordinates: tempCoordinates,
    });
}
```